# C# WinForm Maximize but not full screen, side effect when moving window

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, move, maximize

I set the MaximumSize of a form to a value so that when the user presses the maximize button, the form is still displayed as a window, not full-screen. This works, but there are two side effects of this which I do not want to have:

1. The window is automatically moved to the top left corner of the
   screen;
2. When I move the window with the mouse it is automatically
       resized to the size before I pressed the maximize button.

How can I avoid these side effects?

Edit: Is there a way to center the form horizontally upon pressing the maximize button?

Comment: Please describe in detail what have you tried to do so far.

Comment: You might be in difficulty to fight against OS. I may rather accept the behavior constraint as it is "by design".

Comment: These are both default windows os behaviors. When a window is maximized it automatically takes the entire screen, starting with the top-left corner. If it's max size is smaller then the entire screen, it will still start at the top left corner.  When moving a maximized window it automatically change it's state to restored.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I understand that this behavior is intended by the operating system. Still I would like to circumvent it.

Comment: Is there a way to center the form horizontally upon pressing the maximize button?

Comment: what if this app is run on a display that is smaller than the maximum size that you have set ? Do you set it dynamic ? And how about dual monitor systems ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632626(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could override `WndProc` to capture MaximumSize event
like this

```
    private const int SC_MAXIMIZE = 0xF030;
    private const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_SYSCOMMAND)
        {
            if (m.WParam == new IntPtr(SC_MAXIMIZE))
            {
                this.Size = this.MaximumSize;
                return;
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

this should solve your problem,
however, it is not advisable to go against the design of the operating system. This will cause problems with docking and it goes against the expectations of the users

Comment: Thanks for suggesting a possible solution.